# Voltage between ground and positive / negative terminals, is this correct?

Tags: power-supply, voltage

I recently acquired a used BK Precision 1660 triple output power supply.

Upon powering it up, I did some basic voltage checks.  On both the master and slave outputs, voltage between positive and negative terminals were correct.

However, on the slave output, I actually measured 0.25V between the positive terminal and ground, and also -0.25V between the negative terminal and ground.  This doesn't happen on the master output.

Is this normal?

I'm somewhat new to these things but something tells me this isn't right

Comment: Sorry, for whom doesn't know the instrument: could you please specify what did you expect the voltages to be?

Comment: I would expect there to be zero voltage between positive and ground, and also zero voltage between negative and ground.  The way I understand it, the power supply sets up a potential difference between the positive and negative terminals.  The ground terminal is simply connected to earth ground.  It seems to be common to connect negative and ground, if you want a positive reference above ground.  Or you can connect positive and ground, and then get a negative reference to ground.

Comment: If I'm measuring a potential difference between black terminal and green terminal, then that strap will carry current, which doesn't seem normal.

Comment: You can get the manual here: http://www.k7jrl.com/pub/manuals/b&k/1660/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6595/discussion-between-clabacchio-and-up-the-irons)

Comment: Depends on the measurement impedance. If you were measuring with a 10Megohm DVM and everything else was floating, I'm surprised you didn't see more. Connect the two terminals (- and gnd) with a 1 kilohm resistor and measure again; I'll bet the measurement is much less.

Comment: Indeed, I connected negative (-) and ground terminals with a 3k resistor and the measurement was much less.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the problem and thought you were generating a dual rail voltage and then connecting the negative one to ground. Then if you are sure that you set the slave output voltage to 0 and you see 0.5V instead, it may be like Richman says.

Comment: No problem.  I set the slave output to 0V and I still saw some voltage across negative (-) and ground (same with positive (+)).  I think it's like Richman says; tiny feedback current.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outputs are almost floating with respect to ground but a tiny feedback current both +/- will show the voltage with respect to ground as an offset when only loaded with a 10MOhm probe.

My guess is that is normal for **your old model** and wont have any impact in most applications.    I suspect newer models improved that leakage. But this wont stop you from using tracking mode or Independant or CV , CC or same or complementary polarity earthed at any one point.

Typical use in the old days was separate Analog and Digital grounds wires but the complementary 0~24V outputs grounded at the PSU only with the 5V logic ground, so they do not share logic current noise.